# Excel VBA Running Sum Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UDF that is attempting to tabulate a running sum of a column of numbers. If column A were my data and column B was the UDF output it would look like:

```
Column A | Column B
5        | 5
10       | 15
1000     | 1015
```

And so on.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function runningSum(myCell As range) As Integer

Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim tempSum As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

rowNum = myCell.row
colNum = myCell.Column
tempSum = 0
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    For i = 1 To rowNum
        tempSum = tempSum + ws.Cells(i, colNum).Value
    Next i
    runningSum = tempSum
End With
Exit Function

End Function
```

The issue that I am running into is this: at the 39th and each successive iteration I get a #VALUE error. Help please? Thanks

Comment: What is the value of tempSum at the 39th iteration? Because tempSum is declared as an integer it can only hold a value of 32,767. You might need to change tempSum to a long.

Comment: Are you sure about that 32,767? The reason I ask is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx
It is 33,000 at that iteration. But I wasn't getting an overflow error. No error at all actually.

Comment: VBA <> VB.NET...  And UDF's typically won't raise an error - they just return #VALUE

Comment: In VBA, an integer is only 16 bits.

Comment: Just to confirm, you do know that `=SUM(A$1:A1)` in B1 (then filled down) would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Today is not my best day to look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your numbers are getting too large for `integer` to hold. Try switching the data type to `long`

Answer (score -1):

the below code is useful and worked perfectly
Model:1
Option Explicit
Public Function RunningSum(rng As Range) As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Counter As Long
Dim tempSum As Integer

Counter = WorksheetFunction.Count(rng) + 1
tempSum = 0

For Each Cell In rng
Counter = Counter - 1

tempSum = tempSum + (Cell.Value * Counter)

Next Cell

RunningSum = tempSum

End Function

Model:2

Option Explicit
Public Function RunSumT(rng As Range) As Integer
Dim Cell As Range

Dim tempSum As Integer
Dim tempSum1 As Integer

tempSum = 0
tempSum1 = 0

```
For Each Cell In rng

tempSum = tempSum + (Cell.Value)
    tempSum1 = tempSum1 + tempSum + (Cell.Value)
```

Next Cell

RunSumT = tempSum1 - tempSum

End Function